# Shoenfield's Mathematical Logic Chapter 1 Problem 3

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Edit for context:

An expression in this context is any finite sequence of symbols of the language in question.

"A designator is an expression which is either a term or a formula. Every designator has the form $uv$<sub>1</sub>...$v$<sub>n</sub> where $u$ is a symbol and the $v$<sub>i</sub> are designators, and n is a natural number determined by $u$. For example, if $u$ is a variable, $n = 0$; if $u$ is a $k$-ary function symbol, $n = k$; if $u$ is the existential quantifier, $n = 2$. We call $n$ the index of $u$. We say two expressions are compatible if one can be obtained from the other by adding an expression to the right of the other (possibly the empty expression). If $uv$ and $u'v'$ are compatible, then $u$ and $u'$ are compatible. If $uv$ and $uv'$ are compatible, then $v$ and $v'$ are compatible."

The problem simply reads:

Show that if $uv$ and $vv'$ are designators, then either $v$ or $v'$ is the empty expression.

I don't see why this result is so, I'd like a hint, and if possible, a proof.

Comment: Without access to the book, it is unclear what you are asking.  Please provide more context for the question, and any attempts you have made.

Comment: @graham-kemp I have edited the post with the definition given in the book. Apologies, I assumed it was common knowledge.

Comment: Sadly, a lot of logic has different names for the same object or the same names for the same object. What do you mean by an 'expression' here?

Comment: See [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292880/mathematical-logic-shoenfield-lemma-1).

Comment: @shiranai An expression here is any finite sequence of symbols of a given language. I wasn't aware so much of this depended on the text in question. Thank you, and apologies

Comment: @mauro-allegranza That lemma I understand, there's likely a perfectly trivial step I've missed, or something I've misread. Thank you for posting the link

Comment: As per the linked answer, *designator* is simply a common name for both *terms* and *formulas*, taking into account the fact that, according to official Shoenfield syntax, both are built-up in prefiz notatio; thus, every "readibility" result applies to both.

Comment: For simplicity, you may consider only the *term* case, using the rules to build them : either a *variable* or a *constant* or an expression $f_kt_1 \ldots t_k$.

Comment: So, three cases : (i) $uv$ is $x$. Due to the fact that $u$ is a symbol, $v$ must be the empty expression. The same for (ii) $uv$ is $c$. Last case : $uv$ is $f_k t_1 \ldots t_k$.

Comment: @mauro-allegranza aaaaand I'm an idiot. I knew this to be the case, applied the result correctly, understood this to be a consequence of it, yet somehow didn't think properly interpret the question. Thank you so much for taking the time