# Proof of Lemma 1 in Shoenfield's Mathematical Logic

Tags: logic

I'm having a little trouble with the proof of Lemma 1 (link to screenshot below) in Shoenfield's Mathematical Logic. The overall scheme is easy enough--it's just induction on n. What I don't get is why the induction hypothesis allows us to conclude that $v_i$ is $v_i'$ for $i=1,...,k$ from $v_1...v_k$ and $v_1'...v_k'$ being compatible. That would seemingly require that we know that k is less than n, and as far as I can tell that's not at all guaranteed.

I'm pretty sure that you could argue that $v_i$ and $v_i'$ are the same (or rather, that $u_1$ and $u_1'$ are the same) on the basis of syntax alone. But for that I think you would need to consider a bunch of different cases (the case when v is a function, when it is a predicate, when it is a variable, etc.), which I'd rather not do. So if it's really as simple as invoking the induction hypothesis, I'd love it if someone could explain why.

[Here's a screenshot of the lemma.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uYH2.jpg)

Here's a link to the book: [https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/shoenfield.pdf](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/shoenfield.pdf). Everything is on pages 14 and 15.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292880/mathematical-logic-shoenfield-lemma-1)

Answer (score 1):

Let us record the context inline for reference:

> [image]

Schoenfield's approach considers syntactic objects as strings of symbols and we have to interpret operations as such. So, a designator of the form $\mathbf{uv_{1}\ldots v_{n}}$ is string counterpart of the familiar notation $\mathbf{u(v_{1},\ldots, v_{k})}$, where $\mathbf{v_{i}}$ may be an individual variable or a constant, but also a compound term formed by a function. Thus, $\mathbf{u_{1},\ldots, u_{n}}$ is a sequence of strings while $\mathbf{u_{1}\ldots u_{n}}$ is one string composed by a concatenation of strings.

So, let us call $\mathbf{u_{1}\ldots u_{n}}$ and $\mathbf{u'_{1}\ldots u'_{n}}$, $\mathbf{U}_{n}$ and $\mathbf{U'}_{n}$, respectively. If $\mathbf{U}_{n}$ and $\mathbf{U'}_{n}$ are compatible, $\mathbf{U'}_{n}$ is obtained from $\mathbf{U}_{n}$ by concatenating some string $\mathbf{v'_{1}\ldots v'_{k}}$ to the right end of $\mathbf{U}_{n}$, at least, the initial symbols being identical. Hence, if $\mathbf{u_{1}}$ is of the form $\mathbf{vv_{1}\ldots v_{k}}$, then, $\mathbf{u'_{1}}$ is of the form $\mathbf{vv'_{1}\ldots v'_{k}}$.

Suppose, next, that $\mathbf{v_{1}}$ and $\mathbf{v'_{1}}$ are *not* compatible. Then, $\mathbf{v_{1}}$ must be the last symbol of the initial segment and $\mathbf{v'_{1}}$ must be the first symbol of the adjoined segment. Then, if $\mathbf{u_{1}}$ must be of the form $\mathbf{vv_{1}v_{2}\ldots v_{k}}$, then, $\mathbf{u_{1}}$ must be of the form $\mathbf{vv_{1}v'_{1}\ldots v'_{k}}$. But this is impossible, for the length of the designator $\mathbf{v}$ in $\mathbf{vv_{1}v'_{1}\ldots v'_{k}}$ would be $k+1$. Therefore, $\mathbf{v_{1}}$ and $\mathbf{v'_{1}}$ are compatible. This is a basis for  Schoenfield's remark that

> If $\mathbf{uv}$ and $\mathbf{u'v'}$ are compatible, then $\mathbf{u}$
> and $\mathbf{u'}$ are compatible; if $\mathbf{uv}$ and $\mathbf{uv'}$
> are compatible, then $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v'}$ are compatible.

Consequently, $\mathbf{v_{1}}$ and $\mathbf{v'_{1}}$ are identical.

We set down as the inductive hypothesis that $\mathbf{v_{i}}$ and $\mathbf{v'_{i}}$ are identical for the length $k, i = 1,\ldots k$. Then, it should be difficult to see that the rest follows for $n$ as indicated in the excerpt.

Notice that what Schoenfield does is actually to prove the *unique readability theorem*.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for few days, here is my take on this **Lemma 1**. I'll focus on elaborating Shoenfield's proof, instead of giving alternate proofs as in the answers provided by [Tankut Beygu](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4515254/1167838) and [Mauro ALLEGRANZA](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3293838/1167838).
$ \newcommand{\b}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} $

To begin, I'll put these two given facts as lemmas:

**Lemma 0.1**. If $\b{uv}$ and $\b{u'v'}$ are compatible, then $\b{u}$ and $\b{u'}$ are compatible.

**Lemma 0.2**. If $\b{uv}$ and $\b{uv'}$ are compatible, then $\b{v}$ and $\b{v'}$ are compatible.

Now, we're ready.

**Lemma 1**. If $\b{u_1,\ldots,u_n,u_1',\ldots,u_n'}$ are designators and $\b{u_1\ldots{}u_n}$ and $\b{u_1'\ldots{}u_n'}$ are compatible, then $\b{u_i}$ is $\b{u_i'}$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$.

Proof. We'll apply induction on $n$. When $n = 1$, we want to show that if $\b{u_1}$ is compatible with $\b{u_1'}$, then $\b{u_1}$ is $\b{u_1'}$. So, we'll apply another induction on $\b{u_1}$. For clarity, let $P(d)$ be the property that $\forall{}\b{u_1'}(\text{if $d$ is compatible with $\b{u_1'}$, then $d$ is $\b{u_1'}$})$.

Base case: $P(x)$ where $x$ is a variable with index $0$. Since $\b{u_1'}$ is compatible with $x$, and since $\b{u_1'}$ can't be the empty string or any string longer than $x$ (because these are not valid terms or formulas), $\b{u_1'}$ has to be $x$. Thus, $\b{u_1}$ is $\b{u_1'}$.

Inductive case: $P(\b{vv_1\ldots{}v_k})$ where $\b{v}$ is a symbol of index $k$ and $\b{v_1,\ldots{},v_k}$ are designators, given the inductive hypotheses $P(\b{v_1}),\ldots{},P(\b{v_k})$. Since $\b{u_1'}$ is compatible with $\b{u_1}$, it must have similar form $\b{vv_1'\ldots{}v_k'}$ for the same symbol $\b{v}$ and some designators $\b{v_1',\ldots{},v_k'}$. Then, by Lemma 0.2, we have $\b{v_1\ldots{}v_k}$ compatible with $\b{v_1'\ldots{}v_k'}$; by Lemma 0.1, we have $\b{v_1}$ compatible with $\b{v_1'}$; and finally, by $P(\b{v_1})$, we thus have $\b{v_1}$ is $\b{v_1'}$. By repeating this process (in previous sentence), we'll get $\b{v_i} = \b{v_i'}$ for $i=1,\ldots{},k$. Thus, $\b{u_1}$ is $\b{u_1'}$. And this completes the base case for $n = 1$.

Finally, for the inductive case of $n$, let's suppose Lemma 1 is true for some $n = m-1$, we want to prove it for $n = m$. By the inductive hypothesis and Lemma 0.2, we know that $\b{u_m}$ is compatible with $\b{u_m'}$. Following the reasoning for base case, $\b{u_m}$ is $\b{u_m'}$. This completes the inductive case. Thus, $u_i$ is $u_i'$ for $i = 2,\ldots{},n$.

$\blacksquare$

Hope that this helps! Cheers, happy proving!